# How to properly load heavy collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm learning `ASP.NET Core` and I have some doubts about the loading of an heavy collection of records, let me explain better.

***What I'm trying to do***

In my application, after the login execution, the user will redirected to the `Dashboard Home View`. The `Dashboard` is the place that contains all the functions for an user. The `Dashboard Controller` have also other `Views` like:

- Home
- Analysis
- Performance

Now each `View` need to display to the user a `Table` which contains a list of `Products`, at the bottom of this `Table` there is the content of the `View`.

***Problem***

First problem: is the `Table` redundancy code, which I solved creating a `_PartialView` that contains the `html` of the `Table` that contains the products to display. Coming from c# + WPF I used the same logic of `UserControl`, so this is a good solution for me.

Second problem: the products to display inside the `Table`, these products are downloaded from an `API`, now as I said before, these records must be always displayed in the products `Table` (which is available in different `View` using the `_PartialView`). Imagine that every time the user click on a `Dashboard` item (which load a `Dashboard View`), the `Dashboard Controller` will call this method:

```
 public async Task<List<Products>> GetProducts(string date)
 {
    var client = new RestClient(Url);

    var request = new RestRequest("product/get_products/{date}", Method.GET);
    request.AddUrlSegment("date", date);

    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

    List<Products> products =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(response.Content);
    return products;
 }
```

For me, this is not a really good practice because each time the `_PartialView` will call this method and reload the data, so I need to store somehow this data (a temp store). How can I store these records to the user session without reload each time the `_PartialView` being called?

Between, I have some doubts about the `API` method:
Should I place all the `API` calls inside the `Service` folder? `Repository` folder? Or `Controller` folder?

*Folder tree*

```
View <- Folder
    Dashboard <- Folder
        Home
        Analysis 
        Performance
       _ProductsTable
```

The `View` `Home, Analysis, Performance` load `_ProductsTable` in the following way:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("_LeftSidebar")
```

Comment: Any reason for calling an HTTP endpoint from a controller? Cannot you call that from the View directly? Unless there's a security reason (like different networks), that's an inefficient approach

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto So I can call a `API` method directly from the `View`? As I wrote I know this is a bad practice, I read on the official docs that `Database` interaction can be stored inside the `Repository` folder, but this is an `API` interaction. Perhaps should I create a service? Which is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Of course, an API is an endpoint just like a Controller's Action (your `GetProducts` in the question), so the View can call it. Don't think too much about patterns (like repository, APIs, services), remember to KISS, specially when you are just starting

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Is KISS some technology or some saying in English? Suppose I insert the API call in the `_PartialView`, where would the data be stored?

Comment: My bad, kiss = **K**eep **I**t **S**imple, **S**tupid, ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)). Normally that problem is solved using JavaScript and local storage

Comment: Yeah I agree with @CamiloTerevinto. Calling the API should happen from JavaScript.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Could you show an example of how to consume an API call directly in the `_PartialView`? I'm not able to find anything related on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use view components. They're essentially self-contained modules of functionality that return views, which you can embed in other views, without main view or action having to know about any of it.

First, create a directory call `ViewComponents`. Inside add new class, like `ProductsViewComponent`. Then, you'll want something like:

```
public class ProductsViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public ProductsViewComponent(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(client));
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string date)
    {
       using (var response = await _client.GetAsync($"/"product/get_products/{date}"))
       {
           response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
           var products = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Product>>();
           return View(products);
       }
    }
}
```

Then, create the view, `Views\Shared\Components\Products\Default.cshtml`. Inside, add the HTML to render your list of products. Finally, where you want the product table to appear add:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Products", new { date = myDate })
```

The above code uses `HttpClient` rather than `RestClient`, since honestly, it's completely unnecessary at this point to have a separate library for making HTTP calls. `HttpClient` is built-in and has been extended with functionality in Core to make this much easier, such as the `ReadAsAsync` method used above, which transparently deserializes your JSON response into the generic type argument. Additionally, you now have things like `IHttpClientFactory` which ensures that you have properly scoped `HttpClient` instances. As a result, the above code also assumes adding something like the following to your `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddHttpClient<ProductsViewComponent>(c =>
{
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri('https://api.myservice.com');
    // add default headers and such if you need them
});
```

You can also then use the Polly integration to setup automatic retries, circuit breakers, etc., allowing you handle all sorts of API scenarios such as temporarily unavailable, rate limits, etc. See the full documentation for both [`IHttpClientFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and its [Polly integration](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory) for more info.

Lastly, if this is a scenario where you don't need realtime data, you can also inject an instance of `IDistributedCache` into your view component and add logic to set the result of your API call in that, and retrieve it from there first, before making the call again, allowing you to significantly reduce the load both on your app and the API (especially if do have something where rate limits apply).

Comment: @Chriss Pratt, I was able to try your solution but when I start the software I got this error: `InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' while attempting to activate MyApp.ViewComponents.ProductsViewComponent'.` and also I don't understand the part: `add the HTML to render your list of products` should I add inside the `Default.cshtml` the `@model List<Products>` and iterating over it?

Comment: As I explained in my answer, injecting `HttpClient` depends on adding the code I provided with `services.AddHttpClient` to your `Startup.cs`. As far as `Default.cshtml` goes, yes, you add the HTML for rendering your table of products, complete with the model declaration. It's basically the same as what you're already including in your partial view, likely. Only, now, it will be rendered via the view component.

Comment: I added this line of code inside the startup class: `services.AddHttpClient();` same error

Comment: No. The *exact* code as provided above in the answer. You have to tell where the `HttpClient` instance should be used, done here via the generic type param.

Comment: I added the code of your question (sorry I didn't saw that), but actually the error is still the same. I added the code inside `ConfigureServices` at the top of all

Comment: Please modify your question and post the code exactly as you have it. There's something off somewhere, because the code of above will definitely work.

Comment: @Chriss Pratt maybe I should use also `AddScoped`? I tried: `services.AddScoped<HttpClient>();` but same problem

Comment: No, that's not necessary and wouldn't work anyways. Again, code above works. If it's not working for you, something isn't quite right, but I can't help you further unless I can see exactly what you have. Edit your question.