# Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I created a `ViewComponent` class which call a `REST API` using the `HttpClient`, this is the code:

```
public class ProductsViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public ProductsViewComponent(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(client));
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string date)
    {
        using(var response = await _client.GetAsync($"/product/get_products/{date}"))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var products = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Products>>();
            return View(products);
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' while attempting to activate MyApp.ViewComponents.ProductsViewComponent'

I injected the `HttpClient` in the `ConfigureService` method available in `Startup` in this way:

```
 services.AddHttpClient<FixturesViewComponent>(options =>
 {
    options.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://80.350.485.118/api/v2");
 });
```

UPDATE:

I registered the `ProductsViewComponent` too, same error.

Comment: How have you registered `HttpClient` with your IoC container?

Comment: `ProductsViewComponent` != `FixturesViewComponent`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin I registered both `ViewComponent` but I still got the same error

Comment: All of this code is fine. Did you rebuild after adding the services in `Startup.cs`? Short of that, it might be a dumb question, but are you sure you added it to the right project? Are you sure you actually saved the file? Not sure where else to go with this, because it will just work otherwise. None of this is strange or abnormal.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I was able to fix it adding this: `services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>();` but now the error is: `An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.` the BaseAddress property is null, but I configured it :\

Comment: Nope. That's not correct. Stop fooling around with trying to add `HttpClient` directly. It works with `AddSingleton` because you're literally creating a singleton instance of `HttpClient`, so it knows exactly what to inject, because there's only one choice. However, that's not what you're going for here. `AddHttpClient` works by creating a named client instance within a factory. The factory is registered with the service collection. During injection, an `HttpClient` instance is attempted to be pulled from the factory based on the class name it's being injected into, hence the generic type.

Comment: Long and short, all you need is `AddHttpClient<MyClassNameExactly>()`. It works

Comment: For further reference, see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: @ChrisPratt out of my mind, I used the same code you posted and didn't work. I used this: `services.AddHttpClient<ProductsViewComponent>(options =>
            {
                options.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://80.350.485.118/api/v2");
            });`

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure what to tell you. As you can see from the docs that @KirkLarkin posted a link to, there's nothing complicated about this. You literally add that bit of code and you're off to the races. This is being used by probably millions of developers at this point; I'm using it in my own projects without issue. There's something strange going on with your project, but what exactly is a mystery.

Comment: Check your code one more time with a fine-tooth comb. Make sure the right `AddHttpClient` declarations are in the right project's `Startup.cs`. Save. Close the file and reopen it to verify it's saved. Clean your project. Browse to the project's directory and remove both the `bin` and `obj` directories. Rebuild. Shutdown IIS Express and restart your site/debugging.

Comment: So I've just tried reproducing this issue - I get the same error when trying to inject a `HttpClient` into a `ViewComponent` *specifically*. If I put the `HttpClient` behind (in my case) a `TestService`, which itself takes the `HttpClient` and I inject `TestService` into the `ViewComponent`, it works fine. Now I'm wondering if this doesn't work with a `ViewComponent`, for some reason. I'll dig deeper if I can, but it does bring up the question of *why* do you want to inject a `HttpClient` into a `ViewComponent`...

Comment: @KirkLarkin okay so this is a bug of `ASP.NET Core`, I just want create a `ViewComponent` to load a list of products, you can check the related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52152333/how-to-properly-load-heavy-collection/52168188?noredirect=1#comment91327365_52168188

Comment: @ChrisPratt looking at Kirk Larkin comment I'm not the only guy who have this problem

Comment: Well I'm investigating. If Chris says it works for him, then it's premature to call this out as a bug.

Comment: Well, now I'm second guessing myself. I know I've created view components that call out to APIs, so there's HttpClient involved somewhere in that, but I can't off the top of my head remember whether or not I directly referenced `HttpClient` specifically in a constructor for a view component. Normally, I've got service class wrappers around API stuff, so it's possible I haven't.

Comment: It would be exceedingly *strange* for it not to work just with view components, though. I definitely have working code that injects an `HttpClient` in a tag helper, which seems close enough that both should work.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I trust your words, you know, I'm not an expert of ASP.NET Core 'cause I started learning this a month ago, but if you could test this situation in a ViewComponent, or if there is another way don't be jealous and share your knowledge :)

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yeah, that's why I'm investigating - There should be no difference. I've discovered that if I DI `IHttpClientFactory` into the `ViewComponent` and then use its `CreateClient("ProductsViewComponent")` I get the correct, typed `HttpClient` with the config I set up for it. I'm happy to push what I have to Github if you're interested - Give me a few mins.

Comment: @KirkLarkin I created a chat room here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179489/viewcomponent-injection the comments are getting too long

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**TLDR;**
`ViewComponent`s do not support [typed clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1#typed-clients) out of the box. To resolve this, add a call to `AddViewComponentsAsServices()` onto the end of the call to `services.AddMvc(...)`.

---

After a pretty long [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179489/viewcomponent-injection) that ran off the back of being able to reproduce your issue, we determined initially that the problem being observed is specific to `ViewComponent`s. Even with a call to `IServiceCollection.AddHttpClient<SomeViewComponent>()`, passing an instance of `HttpClient` into `SomeViewComponent`s constructor just refused to work.

However, sitting a new class (`SomeService`) *between* `SomeComponent` and `HttpClient` works as expected. This is what the docs refer to as a [typed client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1#typed-clients). The code looks a bit like this:

```
// Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient<SomeService>();
    // ...
}

// SomeService.cs
public class SomeService
{
    public SomeService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

// SomeViewComponent.cs
public class SomeViewComponent
{
    public SomeViewComponent(SomeService someService)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

As I've already stated, this approach works - the ASP.NET Core DI system is very happy to create the instance of `SomeService` and its typed `HttpClient` instance.

To restate the original problem, take the following example code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient<SomeViewComponent>();
    // ...
}

public class SomeViewComponent
{
    public SomeViewComponent(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In this case, the ASP.NET Core DI system refuses to create an instance of `SomeViewComponent` due to not being able to resolve `HttpClient`. It turns out that this is not specific *just* to `ViewComponent`s: it also applies to `Controller`s and `TagHelper`s (thanks to Chris Pratt for confirming for `TagHelper`s).

Interestingly, the following also works:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient<SomeViewComponent>();
    // ...
}

public class SomeViewComponent
{
    public SomeViewComponent(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("SomeViewComponent")
        // ...
    }
}
```

In this example, we're taking advantage of the fact that the call to `AddHttpClient<SomeViewComponent>` registered a [named client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1#named-clients) for us.

In order to be able to inject `HttpClient` directly into a `ViewComponent`, we can add a call to `AddViewComponentsAsServices` when we register MVC with DI:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(...)
        .AddViewComponentsAsServices();
    // ...
}
```

`AddControllersAsServices` and `AddTagHelpersAsServices` can also be called to add the same support for `Controller`s and `TagHelpers` respectively.

If we look at the docs more closely, it's clear that none of the examples there inject a `HttpClient` into `Controller`s et al - there's simply no mention of this approach at all.

Unfortunately, I don't know enough about the ASP.NET Core DI system in order to be able to explain exactly *why* this works the way it does: The information I've provided above simply explains the *what* along with a solution. Chris Pratt has opened an [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/8418) in Github for the docs to be updated to expand upon this.

Answer (score 92):

I had a similar problem - the problem was in double registration:

```
services.AddHttpClient<Service>();
services.AddSingleton<Service>();  // fixed by removing this line
```

Similar examples [just adding to clarify that it's not specific to AddSingleton, nor related to the order.]

```
services.AddScoped<IService, Service>();  // fixed by removing this line
services.AddHttpClient<IService, Service>();
```

Comment: Resolved my issue as well. Anyone know if this is in the docs anywhere?

Comment: If the AddHttpClient will register the service for me, what lifetime will it be registered with (singleton, scoped, transient)? Is there a way I can ensure it will be singleton, for example?

Comment: @Alejo The service will be registered as Transient when added via `services.AddHttpClient<Service>();` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#typed-clients

Answer (score 5):

I was getting a similar error in my `Azure Function` Version 2. As per [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection), we should be able to add the `IHttpClientFactory` as a dependency. After adding this `DI` in my Azure Function, I was getting the error mentioned below.

> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions: Unable to
>   resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.IHttpClientFactory' while
>   attempting to activate
>   'OServiceBus.Adapter.FetchDataFromSubscription1'

The issue was that I had not override the Configure function to add the `HttpClient` as a registered dependency. So I just created a class called `Statup` in the root directory of my Azure Function as follows.

using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(ServiceBus.Adapter.Startup))]
namespace ServiceBus.Adapter {
    public class Startup: FunctionsStartup {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder) {
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
        }
    }
}
```

After adding this, my function started working properly. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error message trying to inject a wrapper for an external REST service to my controller as an interface. I needed to change the following in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddHttpClient<IMyServiceWrapper>("MyServiceWrapper", client =>
{
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://some_service/api");
}
```

to

```
services.AddHttpClient<IMyServiceWrapper, MyServiceWrapper>("MyServiceWrapper", client =>
{
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://some_service/api");
}
```

in order to be able to use the interface in the constructor of my controller:

```
public MyController(IMyServiceWrapper myService)
{
  _myService = myService;
}
```

Useful for testing myController using a mock service.

Comment: I wish I saw your answer before I added mine, I guess the same thing. Also if I saw it earlier would not spend like a half an hour on it either. Upvoting to bring it up.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you've got two view components mixed up. You're registering the `FixturesViewComponent` as a "named HTTP client" yet you attempt to inject an `HttpClient` instance in the `ProductsViewComponent`.

Changing the HttpClient registration to `ProductsViewComponent` should help:

```
services.AddHttpClient<ProductsViewComponent>(options =>
{
   options.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://80.350.485.118/api/v2");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For me the fix was to add:

```
services.AddHttpClient();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will help, but in my situation this worked:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IMyService,MyService>(); // my usual DI injection of a service that can be mocked
    services.AddHttpClient<IMyService,MyService>(client => {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myservice.com/api");
    }); // notice that I use IMyService for the reference of the registration AND implementation to where it will be injected.
}

public class MyService
{
    public MyService(HttpClient client)
    {
        // client.BaseAddress is properly set here
    }
}

public class MyController : Controller
{
    public MyController(IMyService service) // used by the interface
    {}
}
```

I've tried `services.AddHttpClient<IMyService>()` as well, which would not resolve due to lack of it's constructor.
Also tried `services.AddHttpClient<MyService>()` as above, but it would not resolve the configured instance, as described above.

So the important part is that class that is used to reference the resolved type needs to be used. So this also works:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<MyService>(); // registering the type itself, not via interface
    services.AddHttpClient<MyService>(client => {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myservice.com/api");
    }); // it's ok here, since it will be resolved by it's own type name
}

public class MyService
{
    public MyService(HttpClient client)
    {
        // client.BaseAddress is properly set here
    }
}

public class MyController : Controller
{
    public MyController(MyService service) // used by the type directly
    {}
}
```

It kind of makes sense, but documentation and examples could be better.